# Yii upgrade management

Tags: yii

I'm currently designing a system to allow for upgrades of my modules across all my Yii-powered websites. Does Yii have any sort of api that would allow me to find out the version number of the latest stable release of Yii? I've searched the Yii site and can't find anything, and wondered if anyone else had managed to find a way of doing this.

Comment: Good try. If you found solution, share it in SO to help others :-)

Comment: No. Why you need this? Upgrades of framework is step which must be done by hands, IMHO. You can do it by yourself, and resolve errors which can come. If you have few yii powered websites, they must share 1 version of framework, so upgrading is easy.

Comment: :-) @ineersa I need this because I'm lazy. I maintain a master version of my websites and wanted to be able to upgrade to a newer version of Yii on my local machine, sort out and commit any resulting bugs and errors, then push the changes to my remote websites, along with the newer framework.

Comment: you can fetch the github repo and read the latest release tag. Or set up a githook for tagged commits.. should be simple to setup..

Comment: try composer. And wait (or use), yii2. In 1.1 its hard.

Comment: @Manquer thanks for the tip, this is what I ended up doing. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I sorted this. I used git to get the list of tags from the github repo for Yii, then filtered it for release candidates.

```
$tags = shell_exec('git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/yiisoft/yii.git | egrep -i -v RC\|{}');
    $tagsArray = preg_split("#\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,40}[\s](refs\/tags\/)#", $tags);
    usort($tagsArray, 'version_compare');
    $count = count($tagsArray);
    var_dump($tagsArray[$count-1]);
```

It's dirty, but it did the job!

Comment: If anyone can improve on the preg_split part, please feel free. Regex is not my strong point!